# Colocar Scroll quando está em fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen, height

Estou criando uma página e ela entra em fullscreen, mas tenho problema quando entra em fullscreen o resto do conteúdo que está "abaixo" não é mostrado, só aparece até o limite do monitor.

Estou tentando colocar uma barra de rolagem com `overflow`, porém não estou conseguindo.

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="meio" style="width:768px; margin:0 auto; overflow:auto;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var estado = "";
  $(document).ready(

    function() { 
    var Oaltura = $(document).height(); //altura da página

    var altura = Oaltura + 250;

        $("#meio").css('height', altura+"px");
        $("#meio").load("menu.php"); 

    }

  );
</script>
```

Comment: @OlimonF. Postei o código

Comment: Tenta colocar `max-height` no lugar do `'height'`

Comment: Já tentou colocar `overflow-y:scroll;`?

Comment: sim, já usei, mas não adiantou.

Comment: @Patrick não funcionou

Comment: Além do `max-height`, tente também colocar `overflow: visible`.

Comment: @Patrick não funcionou ainda. Continua não aparecendo os itens que passa do meu monitor

Answer (score 0):

```
.page {
overflow: scroll;
width: 100%
height: 100%
margin: 0 auto;
}

<div id="meio" class="page">
## CONTEUDO ##
</div>
```

tente agora

Comment: só funcionou nas outras páginas, mas na pagina principal que tem o menu que eu preciso não funcionou.